# onCharacteristicChange() is not getting triggered any more after short burst of notifications

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I´m working on an Android BLE app (Android Studio 3.4.2 / Kotlin 1.3.40) and since several days having major issues with it.

Everything works fine, the app (central) can read and write to the peripheral and notification is set for a single characteristic and single notifications of the periperal could also got received and will trigger the onCharacteristicChanged() callback in the way it should be.

But then there is a situation when the peripheral is sending a short burst of notifications (approx. 10 of them) from the same characteristic and then the central is just triggering twice the overridden onCharacteristicChanged() method in the BluetoothGattCallback.

And then there is no more triggering on this onCharacteristicChanged even if there are much more notifications sent from the peripheral (seen and proved with external Bluetooth sniffer).

There are very sporadic situations (1 out of 50-100 tries) where all sent notifications from the peripheral were triggered in the central (Android app).
No, there is no chance to change the burst sequence of the peripheral - it is a black and closed box...

Because I first thought my callback routine on onCharacteristicChanged() is to slow, now I just used a counter which is getting incremented on each trigger event and this counter is shown at the end of the whole BLE sequence, so the callback is as short as possible, but still no success.

There is also nothing in my code which could have reset the notification flag in order not to trigger any more.

Also further attempts to write or read work fine, they still will trigger the overridden onCharacteristicWrite() and onCharacteristicRead() methods. So the BluetoothGattCallback system still seems to work fine.

The same app on iOS with that peripheral works flawlessly...

Have tried on diffent Android smartphones (Pie and Oreo).

Any idea or help would be highly appreciated;-)

Comment: Are you sure it's not the peripheral that acts like this? You should have a look at the hci snoop log or use a ble sniffer to see if it sends more than you get.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Emil, but I already have sniffed with an external nRF Bluetooth sniffer and could see all the burst notifications "on the air" which I´m missing on the Android Smartphone which acts as central. I also already tried HCI Snoop log, but could not detect any written logfile on the smartphone, it seems like this functionality is blocked on my smartphones...

Comment: Just as an additional information: my currently used smartphones for testing are Huawei Y7 and BlackView A60.

Comment: In Android 8.1 the snoop log file was moved to the "Send bug report" feature. So go to developer options and press "send bug report" and send it to yourself. You will then find it in "FS/data/misc/bluetooth/logs" of the zip file.

Comment: I use Android 8.1 and 9 on my 2 test phones. On the 9 phone (BlackView A60) I enabled HCI Snoop log, then switched Bluetooth on and off as suggested, then was running my testing session, then pressed "take bug report" in Android settings, I then get the choice between "interactive report" or "full report", but when I press the button "report" nothing happens and I do not know how to send the report to myself. Do I need to insert an SD card to the phone and do I have to "root" the phone?

Comment: I found this link https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report, but I do not get a notification message that a bug report is created at all... Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: I tried with an inserted SD Card now, but still no luck to create a bug report. Whenever I press the buttonr "report" in Settings there is no further reaction, neither with "interactive report" nor with "full report". What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: It is the same behaviour on the second Smartphone (Huawei Y7): after pressing the "report" button, nothing happens… I do not have a SIM telephone card in both phones, could that be an issue?

Comment: Ok, notifications had been disabled for some applications, now the generation of the bug report is working at least - I will have a look on the HCI data there in the next minutes.

Comment: Ok, the HCI log on WireShark shows also only 2 received notifications from the perihperal notification "burst", so it is the same incomplete information like my "upper level" Android app gets - but the external (correctly "bonded" nRF sniffer shows that there is a real over the air burst of approx. 10 notification on the same characteristic coming very fast). Also my working iOS app can handle this burst of notifications with CoreBluetooth very well. So it seems like the low level Andoid BLE stack is not able to cope with fast notifications on the same characteristic and gets stuck?

Comment: Could you please share the hci log and the sniffer log that correspond to the same connection?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the relevant HCI Snoop log to the "answer" section, see also here [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdm0u.png).

Comment: Here is a related protocol of the external nRF sniffer. It is not the identical situation like the previously shown HCI log but from a nearly identical situation yesterday, because I have some troubles today to get the nRF sniffer bonded to my BT - connection today... https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JGnL.jpg You´ll see the single notifications which works great and got received from Android and then the burst of notifications when the Android system gets stuck after the second one...

Comment: Just for clarification: It is not that important to me that I will get every of the burst notifications of the peripheral (and I cannot stop this weird notification burst of the peripheral in this situation), but the issue is that I do not get any further triggered notifications at all after that burst in the Android system. I also tried to disable notification on central and peripheral before the burst was started and after that enabled it again, but also no success...

Comment: Try to catch the air sniffer log at the same time as the hci log so that they can be compared. Otherwise it's hard to tell where the problem lies.

Comment: I´ll definitely try to do that, but I maybe have found something which is interesting. There is an already made application for Android which is working with that peripheral and I was sniffing with HCI snoop log and I could see that this application is setting "connection interval min. / max." both to 6 (7,5ms)! 
Right now I do not know how to set these parameters that low with Android BLE library, because requestConnectionPriority(CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH), just got me down to an interval time of 12 (15ms). How can I fix the interval time to this low value of 6?

Comment: So at least I had found a workaround to go further: I was able to disable the sending of the burst notifications in the peripheral temporarily while this burst sequence. After the burst - which seems not to get handled well in the Android system - I enabled notifications on the peripheral again. As written before, these burst notifications were not relevant for me. HCI snoop log was a great help for me - thanks for helping me getting this tool to work on my phone;-)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem I once have worked on ble and had similar problem. I had struggled to get it right but had no luck with Android Ble sdk. However when I changed the sdk and used [Android-BLE-Library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library) form Nordic Semiconductor the problems vanished. As written in the readme file of the source

> An Android library that solves a lot of Android's Bluetooth Low Energy problems. The BleManager class exposes high level API for connecting and communicating with Bluetooth LE peripherals. The API is clean and easy to read.

https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library

You can try this out. Hope this helps you.